# How to control gif loop settings in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

I'm able to export a sequence of images as a gif with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i "file:concat.txt" 
-lavfi palettegen=stats_mode=diff[pal],[0:v][pal]paletteuse=new=1:diff_mode=rectangle 
-y "Test.gif"
```

Now, I'm wondering if I can control somehow the loop settings (repeat forever, repeat n times, etc).

I could not find any "loop" on FFmpeg.org documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `-loop` option for the GIF muxer

```
ffmpeg -i input -loop 2 output.gif
```

- `-1` no loop (plays once)
- `0` infinite loop (default)
- `1` loop once (plays 2 times)
- `2` loop twice (plays 3 times)
- etc

See `ffmpeg -h muxer=gif`.